# Populate 10 comboboxes from the same array using VBA in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to create one and the same array to be used for my 10 comboboxes. When the OnClick procedure is activated for a ComboBox, the combobox will be filled with the array.I am no programmer but I use simple VBA to solve some problems. Now I have encountered problems and have no idea how to solve it. Previously, I have only used Excel and linked cell. Now it's Word ...

I want all tests to be visable in the first column of my combobox and the colors in the second column.

My array

Test1,    Blue

Test2,    Green

Test3,    Yellow

Test4,    Black

*I have tried to google around but feel I can not put everything together.*

```
 Private Sub Document_Open()

 ' The location of my array?

 End Sub

 Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()

 ' Load object with array, code for each combobox?

 End Sub
```

[image]

I'm trying to create a simple order form.  I use ActiveX components and document protection.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DropButtonClick` event of the ComboBox to perform actions when the user clicks the dropdown button of a ComboBox control.

Since you want to use the same code for all your ComboBoxes, create a single procedure for populating the list and pass the ComboBox object to it.

To me, it seems simplest to store the list as a delimited string, then use the `Split` function to break that up. First, the items are split into an array. Then loop through that array and split again to get the two entries for a list item, using these to populate a third array that will be assigned to the ComboBox, using the `List` method.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    PopulateList ComboBox1
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_DropButtonClick()
    PopulateList ComboBox2
End Sub

Sub PopulateList(cb As MSForms.ComboBox)
    Dim sListVals As String
    Dim aList As Variant, aCols As Variant, aItems As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'cb.Clear
    sListVals = "Test1,Blue;Test2,Green;Test3,Yellow;Test4,Black"
    aList = Split(sListVals, ";")
    ReDim aItems(UBound(aList), 1)
    For i = LBound(aList) To UBound(aList)
        aCols = Split(aList(i), ",")
        aItems(i, 0) = aCols(0)
        aItems(i, 1) = aCols(1)
    Next
    cb.List = aItems

End Sub
```

Comment: I was the one who failed to put column count to 2, have fixed it now and everything works perfectly. Do you think it's possible to print column 2 also after making your choice?

Comment: Not directly, that I can find, short of reversing the order of the columns. You can use LostFocus to change when the user leaves the control: `Private Sub ComboBox1_LostFocus() : 
    Dim lSelectedIndex As Long : 
    lSelectedIndex = ComboBox1.ListIndex : 
    ComboBox1.Value = ComboBox1.List(lSelectedIndex, 1) : 
End Sub`